# PHP How to optimize this code?

Tags: php, optimization

This code is taking like 15mins to complete, is there anyway it could be optimized?

```
<?php 
$base = 99;
$results = 1975;
$goal = 1000001;
while ($results <= $goal)
{   

    for ( $i=0; $i <= $base; $i++ )
    {
        for ( $j=$i+1; $j <  $base ; $j++  )
        {   

            $hypo = sqrt(( pow($i + $j, 2) )+ pow($base, 2));                   

            if ($hypo == (int) $hypo )
            {
                if ($results == $goal)  
                {
                    echo $i, ' ', $j, ' ',$base , '
';
                    break 3;
                }  
                else
                {
                    $results++;
                }
            }
        }       
    }
    $base++;    
}
echo $base;
?>
```

Comment: You need to provide the code for that?

Comment: Hello:) It would be cool if we can see the code too :)

Comment: What is the aim of this code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP How to optimize this code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9557065/php-how-to-optimize-this-code)

Comment: Use fewer loops :p … you are looping like 1000001 × 4851 (close to 5 billion) times – no wait, even worse, you are incrementing `$base` with each while iteration. That means the last iteration will in the worst case do 100000×1000000 iterations. (or more… this code is confusing)

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Sorry, It s the solution for a euler problem projecteuler.net/problem=86

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a tight loop that's iterated so many times, preincrement is going to be faster than postincrement.
And calling pow() has the overheads of the function call, faster to do the math directly.

```
$base = 99;
$results = 1975;
$goal = 1000001;
while ($results <= $goal)
{

    for ( $i=0; $i <= $base; ++$i )
    {
        for ( $j=$i+1; $j <  $base ; ++$j )
        {

            $hypo = sqrt(( ($i + $j) * ($i + $j) ) + ($base * $base));

            if ($hypo == (int) $hypo )
            {
                if ($results == $goal)
                {
                    echo $i, ' ', $j, ' ',$base , '
';
                    break 3;
                }
                else
                {
                    ++$results;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ++$base;
}
echo $base;
```

That still won't be fast because of the sheer number of iterations, but those two minor changes should reduce the time taken quite significantly... think about 50%-75% faster.

But if you explain what you're actually trying to do - it looks like you're trying to work out pythagorean triangle numbers - perhaps there are more efficient methods than brute force.

**EDIT**

Performance when executed with $goal = 10001:

```
Call time for postincrement and pow() method was 12.4709 seconds
Call time for preincrement and pow() method was 12.4239 seconds
Call time for preincrement method and multiply was 4.9315 seconds
```

SO you can see that postincrement -> preincrement reduces by about 0.05 seconds, but replacing the call to pow() by doing the math directly makes the most significant difference.

Comment: Do you actually have a source/benchmarks to back up that pre-increment is faster that post-increment? It's often thought it is but usually not actually true.

Comment: I've tested it and proven it to be true (preincrement removes the need to store to temporary variable, so reduces those few nanoseconds), but in most cases you won't be calling it enough times for there to be and noticeable difference... with some of my own code (and in this case) the sheer number of increments mean that it is noticeable, though the saving is only a few seconds. The big saving is the pow() function call.

Comment: @Mark Baker Thanks mark, i was trying to solve this problem projecteuler.net/problem=86. There certainly are more elegant solution that brute forcing this, Though i am affraid that i lack the mathematical knowledge to come up with these. The thing is i saw other ppl solution in C, Java, Python and some more that are very similar to mine and yet run under a second, so i was wondering if that was not PHP in cause here..

Comment: Give me a few minutes to rerun, and I'll add some timings to this answer

Comment: @MarkBaker I know that it doesn't need to create the temporary with pre-increment, but if its smart it can optimize that away because the return value is not used, and languages do sometimes make that optimization (though obviously I'm unsure of whether PHP does).

Comment: I really wouldn't put much faith in a `0.3%` difference when benchmarking - I take any bet that if you run this 30times (a minimum for serious benchmarks) and compute std/mean the difference will be statistically insignificant..

Comment: @Voo - believe me, I've done the pre/post increment tests a lot in the past, and I do have faith in it. It's small but I have routines where I'm running millions of iterations and that small difference ceases to be insignificant.... but unless you're in the millions of iterations situation, then it probably isn't worth it. However, I'm not going to spend hours running benchmarks sufficient times to do full stdev, etc. analysis. I wouldn't optimise by that method in isolation, but as part of a series of optimisations.

Comment: @Mark Well I've no idea about php, but I'd hope a postincrement in a single statement is implemented identically to preinc. And I've no php interpreter installed, but simply running your benchmark 30 times, throwing it in a text file and then running eg [this (not at my desktop, so can't post my script)](http://panoskrt.wordpress.com/2009/03/10/shell-script-for-standard-deviation-arithmetic-mean-and-median/) over it, isn't much extra work and the only way to be sure about the results. To paraphrase torvalds If you've ever measured anything and it didn't involve std/mean it wasn't benchmarking

Comment: @Voo - as I said, I have benchmarked it properly before - and when I have more time I'll rerun a set of full benchmarks and post them. I only ran a simple set of tests here, just a few iterations against a much smaller set of loops, mainly to see the effect of the other change to the code that I mentioned. Whether you believe in pre-post increment or not.... do you disagree with the function call to pow() making a difference?